# BabelJS и кириллица

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, ecmascript-6, babel

Подскажите, использую следующий код

```
let reg = new RegExp(`((?:[а-яА-Я]*)(?:${fields.search})(?:[а-яА-Я]*))`, 'g');
```

в результате чего, babel транспилирует его вот в такую кашу

```
var reg = new RegExp("((?:[\u0430-\u044F\u0410-\u042F]*)(?:" + fields.search + ")(?:[\u0430-\u044F\u0410-\u042F]*))", 'g');
```

из-за чего регулярная функция работает некорректно. Может кто сталкивался с таким? Пытался найти о кириллице на сайте babeljs.io, ничего не нашел

Comment: [Javascript + Unicode regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло!

Comment: @СтаниславГрот Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.